# does Windows Update kb3004375 get installed when I install kb3000483? and will kb3004375 not necessarily show in my list of installed updates?

Tags: wsus

I can see KB3000483 in my list of installed updates but I can't see KB3004375 and they seem to go together. Is it the case that if you have KB3000483 then you will also have KB3004375 but the latter will NOT show in your list of installed updates on your server?

...at the URL at the bottom of this post it says

""Update 3004375 is installed ***automatically*** and ***transparently*** together with security update 3000483. Update 3004375 will appear separately in the list of installed updates when it is viewed in the Add or Remove Programs item in Control Panel. Installing both packages together requires only one restart."

Does that quote mean that I won't necessarily see KB3004375 ..and that I will only see KB3000483?
What does ***automatically*** and ***transparently*** actually mean in this context?

I'm looking at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/ms15-011-vulnerability-in-group-policy-could-allow-remote-code-execution-february-10-2015-91b4bda2-945d-455b-ebbb-01d1ec191328

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Microsoft updates frequently supersede older updates - happens frequently. The support article you posted is 6 years old. Normally superseded updates will look after themselves.

Comment: We've actually determined that KB3000483  applies to server 2012 r2 and KB3004375 only applies to Server 2012...this isn't stated exactly in the MS docs but it's what our WUS server is telling us..thanks for your time in considering this issue